# Summer Tag Rename 2015

Tags: discussion, tagging

When it comes to editing tags I usually wait for RoflcoptrException to be in the chat and I ping him directly. In case I know he's on holiday I open a meta thread every time I see a tag that should be renamed. I'm not sure this is the most efficient workflow, for a number of reasons.

How about compiling a list of tags to be renamed to make it easier for the mods?

Below is a community wiki answer to be edited by adding the tags to be renamed and the edit status. The mods can then monitor the post for edits and act accordingly.

Comment: Excellent idea. I'll track this meta thread as well for any edits needed.

Comment: As I've just returned to the other hemisphere, the name 'Summer' is biased ;)

Comment: @pnuts Excellent. Thanks for advertising us.

Comment: @MarkMayo: [For 2016 the bias has been cancelled out.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3538)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summer Tag Rename 2016](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/summer-tag-rename-2016)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Instructions

Mark the tags to be renamed below.

- The html arrow symbol ⇒ denotes renaming operations
- The html arrow symbol ← denotes synonym-creation operations

Once done, mark the renamed tags using the html tick ✔ using the following html code:

```
&#10004;
```

---

#### Old name - New Name - Status

- [philippine-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philippine-citizens) ⇒ [filipino-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filipino-citizens) - ✔
- [bangladesh-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bangladesh-citizens) ⇒ [bangladeshi-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bangladeshi-citizens) - ✔
- [iran-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iran-citizens) ⇒ [iranian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iranian-citizens) - ✔
- [afghanistan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afghanistan-citizens) ⇒ [afghan-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afghan-citizens) - ✔
- [singapore-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singapore-citizens) ⇒ [singaporean-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singaporean-citizens) - ✔
- [the-gambia-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-gambia-citizens) ⇒ [gambian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gambian-citizens) - ✔
- [myanmar-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myanmar-citizens) ⇒ [myanma-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myanma-citizens) - ✔
- [slovenia-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slovenia-citizens) ⇒ [slovenian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slovenian-citizens) - ✔
- [cave](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cave) ⇒ [caves](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caves) - ✔
- [grand-prix](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-prix) ⇒ [grands-prix](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grands-prix) - ✔
- [visa-on-arrival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-on-arrival) ⇒ [visas-on-arrival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visas-on-arrival) - ✔
- [visa-cancellations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-cancellations) ⇒ [visa-cancellation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-cancellation) (rare case where singular is better because it also covers the act of cancellation, about which we do have questions) - ✔
- [uk-resident](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-resident) ⇒ [uk-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-residents) - ✔
- [botswanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botswanian-citizens) ⇒ [batswana-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batswana-citizens) - ✔
- [safari](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safari) ⇒ [safaris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safaris) - ✔

#### Synonym Target - Origin - Status

- [burmese-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burmese-citizens) ← [myanma-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myanma-citizens) - ✔
- [car-hire](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-hire) ← [car-rentals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-rentals) - ✔
- [ride-sharing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ride-sharing) ← [rideshare](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rideshare) - ✔
- [filipino-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filipino-citizens) ← [philippines-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philippines-citizens) - ✔
- [filipino-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filipino-citizens) ← [philippine-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philippine-citizens) - ✔
- [hnd](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hnd) ← [tokyo-haneda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokyo-haneda) - ✔
- [us-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens) ← [usa-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa-citizens) - ✔
- [trinidanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinidanian-citizens) ← [tobagonian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tobagonian-citizens) - ✔
- [work](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) ← [working](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working) - ✔
- [t-and-t-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-and-t-citizens) ← [trinidadian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinidadian-citizens) - ✔
- [t-and-t-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-and-t-citizens) ← [tobagonian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tobagonian-citizens) - ✔
- [batswana-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batswana-citizens) ← [botswanian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botswanian-citizens) - ✔
- [visa-refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusal) ← [visa-denial](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-denial) - ✔
- [us-visa-waiver-program](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-visa-waiver-program) ← [vwp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vwp) - ✔