# Summer Tag Rename 2016

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since it's no longer [Summer 2015](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3277) and the predecessor to this question contained a reference to a specific point in time, it's time for a new Tag Renaming topic.

So let's once more compile a list of tags to be renamed to make it easier for the mods.

Below is a community wiki answer to be edited by adding the tags to be renamed and the edit status. The mods can then monitor the post for edits and act accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

### Instructions

Mark the tags to be renamed below.

- The html arrow symbol ⇒ denotes renaming operations
- The html arrow symbol ← denotes synonym-creation operations

Once done, mark the renamed tags using the html tick ✔ using the following html code:

```
&#10004;
```

---

#### Old name - New Name - Status

- [wrong-example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrong-example) ⇒ [right-example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right-example) - ✔
- [cafe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cafe) ⇒ [cafes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cafes) - ✔
- [vacation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacation) ⇒ [vacations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacations) - ✔
- [aircraft](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) ⇒ [aircrafts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircrafts) - will not be merged, as explaind in the comments
  ([Can we create a new tag for "does my visa last until midnight" kind of questions?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/can-we-create-a-new-tag-for-does-my-visa-last-until-midnight-kind-of-questions/3739?noredirect=1#comment11010_3739))
- [battery](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) ⇒ [batteries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) - ✔
- [jr-pass](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jr-pass) ⇒ [jr-passes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jr-passes)
- [invitation-letter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invitation-letter) ⇒ [invitation-letters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invitation-letters)
- [visa-duration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-duration) ⇒ [visa-expiration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-expiration)
- [airport-terminal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-terminal) ⇒ [airport-terminals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport-terminals)

#### Synonym Target - Origin - Status

- [example-tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-tag) ← [example-synonym](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-synonym) - ✔
- [borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders) ← [land-borders](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/land-borders)
- [luggage-storage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage-storage) ← [left-luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-luggage) - ✔
- [bookings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookings) ← [airline-booking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airline-booking)

Comment: "Aircrafts" is not a standard English word. The usual plural is just "aircraft" much like "fish" and "sheep".

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think borders and land-borders should be synonyms. Many questions are specifically about entering a country by land.

Comment: @J.Constantine: Yes but what questions are about borders that are not about land borders? Most real travel questions are about details of crossing borders. How would a user know which to pick? Factoid questions about borders are less important than real travel questions and also work just as well with either tag. Are we lacking a needed [tag:maritime-borders]? Are there many questions about entering a country other than by land which would use the plain [tag:borders] tag for some reason?

Comment: @hippietrail I'm thinking of airports, but to be honest, haven't looked at how many questions there are

Comment: PINGING DA MODS! Do you still look here or should we we start a new "Autumn tag rename 2016"?

Comment: @mindcorrosive: Any corrosive minds or other mods available to bring this up to date?

Comment: @ankurbanerjee: Any Ankurs or other mods available to bring this up to date?

Comment: Since, despite trying multiple times to get an OP to look at the newer unaddressed portions of this question, I'm going to open a new version with just the bits that have not been acted upon yet.