# Can we create a new tag for "does my visa last until midnight" kind of questions?

Tags: discussion

There are several questions on the inclusiveness of a certain visa stamp:

[Entry stamp of Ireland - is "until" date inclusive?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/entry-stamp-of-ireland-is-until-date-inclusive)

[Is it acceptable to leave USA on the 90th day of a stay?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31642/leaving-the-us-at-the-end-of-90-days)

[Schengen area 90 days limit: Can I leave on the 91st day?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47035/schengen-area-90-days-limit-can-i-leave-on-the-91st-day)

Can we create a special tag for these kinds of situations? Perhaps [end-of-visa-duration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-of-visa-duration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest visa-duration or visa-expiration

Comment: visa-duration it is then!

Comment: @JonathanReez Wouldn't visa duration be more likely to be confused for allowed duration of stay?  I would suggest visa-validity or visa-expiration.

Comment: @phoog only mods can edit tags, right?

Comment: @JonathanReez I do not know

Comment: @Jon Yes, only mods can *edit* tags. And suggesting synonyms is a pain in the #%& until you have a proper score in either tag so … the mod is quickest ;)

Comment: visa-validity is better imo... it covers all aspects, whether it is duration, expiration, etc.