# Spring Tag Rename 2020

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since it's no longer [Summer 2016](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3538) and the predecessor to this question contained a reference to a specific point in time, it's time for a new Tag Renaming topic.

So let's once more compile a list of tags to be renamed to make it easier for the mods.

Below is a community wiki answer to be edited by adding the tags to be renamed and the edit status. The mods can then monitor the post for edits and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

### Instructions

Mark the tags to be renamed below.

- The html arrow symbol ⇒ denotes renaming operations
- The html arrow symbol ← denotes synonym-creation operations

Once done, mark the renamed tags using the html tick ✔ using the following html code:

```
&#10004;
```

---

#### Old name - New Name - Status

- [wrong-example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrong-example) ⇒ [right-example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right-example) - ✔

#### Synonym Target - Origin - Status

- [example-tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-tag) ← [example-synonym](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/example-synonym) - ✔